# Test Rules AlertManager FAILED: yaml: unmarshal errors: line 1: field groups not found in type main.unitTestFile

Tags: alert, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

please help i got error message when testing alert manager below

```
 promtool check rules /etc/prometheus/alert.rules.yml
 Checking /etc/prometheus/alert.rules.yml
 SUCCESS: 3 rules found

 promtool test rules /etc/prometheus/alert.rules.yml
 Unit Testing:  /etc/prometheus/alert.rules.yml
 FAILED:
 yaml: unmarshal errors:
 line 1: field groups not found in type main.unitTestFile
```

my **`alert.rules` configuration** like below :

```
      cat /etc/prometheus/alert.rules.yml
      groups:
      - alert: MemoryFree10%
        expr: node_exporter:node_memory_free:memory_used_percents >= 90
        for: 5m
        labels:
          severity: critical
        annotations:
          summary: "Instance {{ $labels.instance }} hight memory usage"
          description: "{{ $labels.instance }} has more than 90% of its memory used."
      - alert: DiskSpace10%Free
        expr: node_exporter:node_filesystem_free:fs_used_percents >= 90
        labels:
          severity: moderate
        annotations:
          summary: "Instance {{ $labels.instance }} is low on disk space"
          description: "{{ $labels.instance }} has only {{ $value }}% free."
      - alert: ExporterDown
        expr: up == 0
        for: 5m
        labels:
          severity: warning
        annotations:
          summary: "Exporter down (instance {{ $labels.instance }})"
          description: "Prometheus exporter down\n  VALUE = {{ $value }}\n  LABELS: {{ $labels }}"
```

Is there any missing or incorrect our file alert rules ?

please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When checking syntax using promtool for config file, you've to use "**./promtool check config prometheus.yml**"
This prometheus.yml is a parent file, which would call the prometheus rule file prometheus_rules.yml.
Therefore, when checking syntax using promtool for rule file, you've to use "**./promtool check rules prometheus_rules.yml**"

Answer (score 0):

You are running the unit test on the alerting rule file. You should write test file first and then run the unit test on the test file by `promtool test rules test.yml`.

Here is a demo from https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/unit_testing_rules/

**alerts.yml**

```
# This is the rules file.

groups:
- name: example
  rules:

  - alert: InstanceDown
    expr: up == 0
    for: 5m
    labels:
        severity: page
    annotations:
        summary: "Instance {{ $labels.instance }} down"
        description: "{{ $labels.instance }} of job {{ $labels.job }} has been down for more than 5 minutes."

  - alert: AnotherInstanceDown
    expr: up == 0
    for: 10m
    labels:
        severity: page
    annotations:
        summary: "Instance {{ $labels.instance }} down"
        description: "{{ $labels.instance }} of job {{ $labels.job }} has been down for more than 5 minutes."
```

**test.yml**

```
# This is the main input for unit testing.
# Only this file is passed as command line argument.

rule_files:
    - alerts.yml

evaluation_interval: 1m

tests:
    # Test 1.
    - interval: 1m
      # Series data.
      input_series:
          - series: 'up{job="prometheus", instance="localhost:9090"}'
            values: '0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0'
          - series: 'up{job="node_exporter", instance="localhost:9100"}'
            values: '1+0x6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0' # 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
          - series: 'go_goroutines{job="prometheus", instance="localhost:9090"}'
            values: '10+10x2 30+20x5' # 10 20 30 30 50 70 90 110 130
          - series: 'go_goroutines{job="node_exporter", instance="localhost:9100"}'
            values: '10+10x7 10+30x4' # 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 10 40 70 100 130

      # Unit test for alerting rules.
      alert_rule_test:
          # Unit test 1.
          - eval_time: 10m
            alertname: InstanceDown
            exp_alerts:
                # Alert 1.
                - exp_labels:
                      severity: page
                      instance: localhost:9090
                      job: prometheus
                  exp_annotations:
                      summary: "Instance localhost:9090 down"
                      description: "localhost:9090 of job prometheus has been down for more than 5 minutes."
      # Unit tests for promql expressions.
      promql_expr_test:
          # Unit test 1.
          - expr: go_goroutines > 5
            eval_time: 4m
            exp_samples:
                # Sample 1.
                - labels: 'go_goroutines{job="prometheus",instance="localhost:9090"}'
                  value: 50
                # Sample 2.
                - labels: 'go_goroutines{job="node_exporter",instance="localhost:9100"}'
                  value: 50
```

Then you can run `promtool test rules test.yml`, you will get result like

```
Unit Testing:  test.yml
  SUCCESS
```

Answer (score -1):

Your configuration is missing rules.

```
    groups:
    - name: alert.rules
      rules:
      - alert: HighRequestLatency
      .....
```

https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/alerting_rules/

Comment: <pre>
hi amjad, thanks for reply. but i already test with using rules still error
groups:
  - name: alerting.rules
    rules:
      - alert: ExporterDown
        expr: up == 0
        for: 5m
        labels:
          severity: warning
        annotations:
          summary: "Exporter down (instance {{ $labels.instance }})"
 
promtool test rules /etc/prometheus/alert.rules.yml
Unit Testing:  /etc/prometheus/alert.rules.yml
  FAILED:
yaml: unmarshal errors:
  line 1: field groups not found in type main.unitTestFile
</pre>

Comment: i have added your complete yml file and ran promtool and everything is success, are you sure your yaml is correct or formatted?
```
groups:
- name: rules
  rules:
  - alert: MemoryFree10%
    expr: node_exporter:node_memory_free:memory_used_percents >= 90
    for: 5m
    labels:
      severity: critical
    annotations:
      summary: "Instance {{ $labels.instance }} hight memory usage"
      description: "{{ $labels.instance }} has more than 90% of its memory used."
```

Comment: ehmm strange i trying always error   FAILED:
yaml: unmarshal errors:
  line 1: field groups not found in type main.unitTestFile

Comment: Could you put it in a gist ?

Comment: sorry @MichaelDoubez what the meaning of gist ?